# How can I use Angular service function?It throws Error:"Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea why I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I need to get marker data from database.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**MainApp.js**

```
app.controller('GoogleMapController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log($scope);
    var init = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost/MySQLHandler/MySQLHandler.php',{//Error occurs here
            method:"GET",       
            params: {id: '5'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('Yes');
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // Handle the error
        });        
    };
    init();
});
```

**HTML**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the string name of the dependency you're attempting to use. You need to add `'$http'` into the array:

```
app.controller('GoogleMapController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

You can put the dependency name directly into the function without also passing its name as a string ONLY if you aren't using the array syntax:

```
app.controller('GoogleMapController', function($scope, $http) {
```

NOTE! The array syntax is needed if you will be minifying your code, unless you plan on using ng-min.

Comment: would add ngmin will handle this and will save you from writing more verbose code

Comment: @shaunhusain yep, I was just writing a note about it. Though personally, I don't prefer to use ng-min.